# Send listboxfor to controller

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form in my view that contains a listbox. The user adds values to the listbox.

When the user pushes the 'submit' button I want all the values in the listbox to be placed in my models property that is a List.

Here is the Listbox in my view:

```
 @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Ingredients, new List<Ingredient>(), new { @class = "form-control" , @id = "Ingredients"})
```

This line gives an error that is that the List has to contain SelectListItem. Even if i change to that, and also change it in my view model, it still doesn't work.

This is my viewmodel:

```
 public class RecipeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public List<Ingredient> Ingredients { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    public List<RecipeModel> Recipes { get; set; }
}
```

This is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public void SaveRecipe(RecipeModel model)
    {
        RecipeDb.SaveRecipe(Mapper.Map<Recipe>(model));
    }
```

What I want is that in the controller, I want the models List Ingredients to be populated by all the items/values in the listbox from the view but I cant figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A multiple select post back an array of simple values (say `[1, 4, 7]` or `["Recipe 2", "Recipe 4" ]` depending on the values of the selected options). You cannot bind `ListBoxFor` to a collection of complex objects. Your view model needs to have a property to bind to. Assuming typeof `Ingredient` contains properties `int ID` and `string Name`, then you view model would be something like

```
public class RecipeViewModel
{
  public int[] SelectedIngredients { get; set; }
  public SelectList IngredientList { get; set; }
}
```

Then the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  RecipeViewModel model = new RecipeViewModel();
  // Populate the collection of available ingredients
  model.IngredientList = new SelectList(db.Ingredients, "ID", "Name");
  // if you want to pre select some options, then: model.SelectedIngredients = new int[] { 1, 4, 7 };
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(RecipeViewModel model)
{
  // model.SelectedIngredients will contain the ID's of the selected ingredients
}
```

And in the view

```
@model RecipeViewModel
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  ....
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedIngredients, Model.IngredientList)
  ....
}
```